# Node ID and node title in panels page URL

Tags: panels

I would like to set up Panels page URL with this pattern: `my-site/[node:nid]/[node:title]` (i.e. `my-site/34/node-34-title`).

I don't exactly understand how the Panels page URL setting works with arguments. I can set up the path to `my-site/%nid/%title` but how can I set it up so that `%nid = [node:nid]` and `%title = [node:title]`?

**My questions:**

1. How do I configure Panels page to do that?
2. Panels panes are populated with Views field. Is there anything to do in views to get these arguments?
3. How can I get transliterated node titles, using Pathauto or Transliterate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to change the url with panel page manager:

The path pattern is a way to target some page by there route.

1 - If you want to modify the url pattern, use instead the  Pathauto pattern tool with Token. ex: /[node:title].

Once you build your pattern, it will create some alias every time you create a node, but the internal url is still /node/%node, so you have to use this one to target the nodes pages in the panel configuration.

2- Then, if you need to use the node title in a  panel region, you can create a block view with title, and add a the contextual filter on the ID field, by taking is value frome the url.
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=drupal+8+add+contextual+filter&ia=web

3- If you build a pattern like in 1 - with pathauto and token - the resulting alias will be a transliteration of the node title.

Comment: I first built a pathauto alias pattern like that /[node:nid] and use the /node/%node in Panels. Everything works fine, thank you. I guess that it will also work if my pathauto pattern alias is /[node:nid]/[node:title].

Comment: Pathauto is even more powerful : you can juste set:    /[node:title]. It's not using the id to find the node but it save the url and associate it with the internal path /node/[id]. Don't forgot to validate my answer above :p.

Comment: You're right. After tested several patterns in Pathauto URL aliases, I understood that whatever you set it will be used in Panels /%node URL. In fact the node ID is always used by the system. Powerfull !!! Thanks for your help.